# Definition of Ito Integral

Tags: stochastic-calculus

In Kartazas and Shreve, the integral for Bounded Progressively measurable processes is defined first. Then, for Bounded measurable processes ($f(t,\omega)$), the authors say that there exists a progressively measurable modification and show how to define an integral in this case.

For a bounded, measurable and adapted process the progressively measurable 
modification is also bounded (I found this from P.A. Meyer's book Probability and Potentials). Therefore, if $g(t,\omega)$ is the modification
we know that there exist elementary $g_n(t,\omega)$ such that
$E\int_S^T(g(t,\omega)-g_n(t,\omega))^2dt \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Then, 
it seems that $E\int_S^T(f(t,\omega)-g_n(t,\omega))^2dt \to 0$. I do not understand why the authors [proceed in a more complicated manner](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=w0SgBQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=karatzas%20shreve&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BOGMVdDIIseIuATdmYEo&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=karatzas%20shreve&f=false) (see the page which contains equation 2.8 in section 3.2) to define the integral.